# Start running a batch file when it receives a signal

Tags: batch-file, backup, server, database-backups

I have a long backup job running on one server that needs to run before another backup job on another server. Is there any way I could have Server A signal Server B to start? These backup jobs take a long time as need to be done on weekend days when there's no one around. How would I go about having unsupervised server A (which would finish its backup job late on a Saturday night) signal unsupervised server B to start it's job? Could I do with a .bat file or script?

Thanks,
Eoghan

Comment: This is not a programming question. You should either consider posting it on another StackExchange site (like ServerFault oder SuperUser) or ask a specific question about (batch-) programming.
And the short answer to your question is: Yes you can do it with a .bat-file.

Answer (score 2):

`Waitfor` sends signals to batch files and waits in batch files for that signal.

See `waitfor /?`.

It seems about batch to me.